# Trying to get a functioning /dev/sda again after nuking it with dd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

On my attempt at getting an Arch install on my laptop I messed up and I wanted to format the partitions to start all over, so I typed this command into the live session:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=4
```

Now I just want a usable hard drive I can install some version of Linux on. Every time I type in `cgdisk /dev/sda` it aborts. I can get sessions from live USBs. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Why does `cgdisk` abort? Any message it writes before it exits?

Comment: The creator of `gdisk`/`cgdisk` is Rod Smith,
 he is [with us on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/171594/rod-smith?tab=profile). It seems he's quite active here, helping fellow users. If `cgdisk` misbehaved, he may be interested in investigating the issue. First you should address [styrofoam fly's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1219746/trying-to-get-a-functioning-dev-sda-again-after-nuking-it-with-dd#comment1782513_1219746), no doubt about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just create a partition table.

If `cgdisk` aborts, just use different program, like `parted`. In order to create a new partition table write:

1. `sudo parted /dev/sdX`
2. `mklabel msdos` (valid label types are one of `aix`, `amiga`, `bsd`, `dvh`, `gpt`, `mac`, `msdos`, `pc98`, `sun`, `loop`).

`cgdisk` may abort/crash because of some kind of strange data it reads (however we can't tell - you have not told us what does it say upon exit). Wiping drive partition table with zeros (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX count=5 bs=10M`) should make `cgdisk` work on sane input and perform correctly.